# Use twisted ,how can I keep the client object

Tags: python, object, twisted

Here is my simple twisted server code:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol,Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

class MultiEcho(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.recvBuf = ""
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.echoers.append(self)
        print self.factory.echoers

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.recvBuf += data
        self.transport.write(data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.echoers.remove(self)

class MultiEchoFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.echoers=[]

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return MultiEcho(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reactor.listenTCP(4321, MultiEchoFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

Use 'telnet 127.0.0.1 4321' ,will print a list:

```
[<__main__.MultiEcho instance at 0x0000000002EA6B08>]
```

add another 'telnet 127.0.0.1 4321',the list is:

`[<__main__.MultiEcho instance at 0x0000000002EA6B08>, <__main__.MultiEcho instance at 0x0000000002EA6EC8>]`

I know a client is a protocol object's instance ,and the list is `MultiEchoFactory.echoers`,so I want to keep the list,
import  them in another .py file use `list[n].transport.write(somedata)`.

I try `from myserver import MultiEchoFactory`,but the MultiEchoFactory.echoers is empty.
I also rewrite the code

```
class MultiEchoFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.echoers=[]
```

to

```
class MultiEchoFactory(Factory):
    echoers=[]
```

But I still can't use the protocol list in another .py file.
So,what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to save it in `buildProtocol()`, i.e.:

```
class MultiEchoFactory(Factory):
    echoers=[]

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        echoer = MultiEcho(self)
        MultiEchoFactory.echoers.append(echoer)
        return echoer
```

Comment: Sorry guys,I tried but it's not useful.from XX import MultiEchoFactory,the echoers = []

Comment: @Blunt: I updated my answer, but be careful using global state like `echoers` list.

Comment: Sorry,still can't work...Maybe I can't use twisted like that?

Comment: I use your code,but raise error like:   exceptions.AttributeError: class MultiEchoFactory has no attribute 'append'.  I know MultiEchoFactory is not a list ,so can't use MultiEchoFactory.append.I think maybe twiesed can't import the object to other ,py and use transport.write

Comment: Oh, I made small typo. Check it out. BTW, you may guessed that typo on your own.